# HTTP Request GET method. How can I solve this on Spring RestTemplate(getForEntity) + JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

> I want to retrieve information through a library that attacks Codewars API whit my user on JSON format.The request method(GET, gives you back a JSON with information about your user) https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/(here you put your user name) .First of all I added my name at the end of this URI to check that it works right and returns a JSON. After that I used a converter (JSON to Java) to get back the Java code corresponding of my JSON.  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
>   My JSON:

```
 {
username: "heremyusername",
name: null,
honor: 2,
clan: "pepito",
leaderboardPosition: 500793,
skills: null,
ranks: {
overall: {
rank: -8,
name: "8 kyu",
color: "white",
score: 2
},
languages: {
java: {
rank: -8,
name: "8 kyu",
color: "white",
score: 2
}
}
},
codeChallenges: {
totalAuthored: 0,
totalCompleted: 1
}
 }
```

> My method:

```
public User getUser() {
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
User user = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/(here my user name)", User.class).getBody();
return  ;
}
```

> Problem is that JSON to Java has given me back 6 differents Java class. One of them:

```
package entities;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

@JsonPropertyOrder({
"overall",
"languages"
})

public class Ranks {

@JsonProperty("overall")
private Overall overall;

@JsonProperty("languages")
private Languages languages;

@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, 
Object>(); 


@JsonProperty("overall")
public Overall getOverall() {
return overall;
}

@JsonProperty("overall")
public void setOverall(Overall overall) {
this.overall = overall;
}

@JsonProperty("languages")
public Languages getLanguages() {
return languages;
}

@JsonProperty("languages")
public void setLanguages(Languages languages) {
this.languages = languages;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

> It give me back another 5 Java class(Java,Overall,Mail,Languages,CodeChallenge) with same format(getters,setters...) So method public User getUser() its wrong, I don´t know what it returns,if I have to make it void or what class to use because I want to retrieve all information not only a portion.
>   User is a JavaBean whose fields are Integer id and String username.